# VPN Connection dropping from PC connected to internet via wifi

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, vpn, wireless-router

My PC is connected to the internet via wifi through a Ubee router.

Lately, my vpn connection has been dropping a lot.
When it drops, I cannot reconnect to the vpn server right away. I have to wait about 4 to 5 minutes, then I can reconnect.

When I cannot reconnect, the regular internet connection is fine.

When I cannot reconnect, if I try to connect to the vpn on my phone( connected to the same wifi router ), it connects right away and when that happens, I can instantly connect from my PC as well. It is as if my phone connecting to the vpn server unblocks something on the router

Hopefully one of you have heard of such a thing.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 2):

My wife experienced this in our new house (Spectrum), with the same symptoms.  Our solution was to relocate the router closer to her desk and use an ethernet cable.  The problem immediately went away and has not returned.

The difference from our last location was we were using an Apple Airport, which didn't have the problem.  The router in this house is an older Rosewill RT-N150.  VPN's can be sensitive to even momentary connection losses.  The Operating System sends an event if it detects a drop in connectivity on a wireless connection.  I have seen the Rosewill router drop for only a second or two, then recover.  The quick recovery means a browser will still work, since it is not using a static connection. The VPN can see this loss as requiring a connection reset, reauth, etc.

I would suggest borrowing a newer router from someone and see if that solves the problem.  Also check the channel saturation where you are at: too many SSID's in the wireless AP list can mean that the packet traffic is heavy and subject to a lot of collisions.  This means many retries and more of a chance the connection will be disrupted.

If at all possible, switch to an ethernet connection.  It is much better and much faster.